# git svn status - showing changes that are not committed to svn

Tags: git-svn

I'm looking for a command in git-svn that will show me the changes I have committed to my git repository but that aren't yet committed to the central svn repository.  I'm looking for something that works like svn status, but I'm using git-svn, and unfortunately, `git svn status` is not a valid command.

I tried `git status` but it does not solve this problem, as it shows changes that haven't been committed to my local git repo.

I also tried `git svn dcommit --dry-run`, but it doesn't tell me which files are ready to be dcommitted - it only shows the repository URL.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Assuming the branch for the remote Subversion repository is at remotes/git-svn, run the following:

```
git svn fetch
```

The fetch will ensure that remotes/git-svn is up-to-date. (Thanks to Mark for pointing this out in a comment.)

```
git diff --name-status remotes/git-svn
```

This should show you the name and status of all the files that have been committed to git but not to Subversion, just like the `svn status` command.

In case you're not sure where the branch containing the Subversion remote repository is located, you can run:

```
git branch -a
```

which should produce output similar to the following:

```
* master
  remotes/git-svn
```

You can probably guess from this that the remote Subversion repository is in remotes/git-svn.

Comment: It might be worth adding a note at the beginning of the answer to the effect that it's a good idea to run `git svn fetch` first to make sure that `remotes/git-svn` is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
git diff git-svn HEAD -d
```

or if you have difftool specified:

```
git difftool git-svn HEAD -d
```